# Running openvas-setup

Tags: linux, security, openvas

I am following this tutorial on a CentOS 7 box: https://linuxincluded.com/installing-openvas-on-centos-7/.  When I run openvas-setup, I get the following:

```
Updating NVTs....
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
Download not successful: too many failed attempts
  rerun  /usr/sbin/greenbone-nvt-sync manually

Updating CERT data...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
Download not successful: too many failed attempts
  rerun  /usr/sbin/greenbone-certdata-sync manually

Updating SCAP data...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
su: user openvas does not exist
Retrying in 3 seconds...
Download not successful: too many failed attempts
  rerun  /usr/sbin/greenbone-scapdata-sync manually

Updating OpenVAS Manager certificates: Complete
```

When I try to add a user named 'openvas', I get this:

```
adduser: group openvas exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.
```

Running the first command manually, I get this:

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/greenbone-nvt-sync: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the script runs a wrong command to add user openvas. You should run the following command first:

```
useradd openvas -g openvas
```

Then run the following to fix "-bash: /usr/sbin/greenbone-nvt-sync: No such file or directory"

```
ln -s /usr/bin/greenbone-nvt-sync /usr/sbin/greenbone-nvt-syn
ln -s /usr/bin/greenbone-nvt-sync /usr/sbin/greenbone-nvt-sync
```